# convert string to date and write back into NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, nsmutablearray, nsdate

I have a NSMutableArray I get by loading a plist into it. The date field comes in as a string and i want to change it into a nsdate. I can change an nsstring into an nsdate.

My array is an array of objects like the one below;

> {
>       Date = "1/1/2009"
>       Description = "Have you ever looked at a badger and thought i wonder how far you could fire that out of a cannon? Well this talk is for you";
>       File = "http://www.badgerCannon.org.uk/mp3/070310pm.mp3";
>       Series = "The Badger planet";
>       Speaker = "Will Ferell";
>   Title = "Is it a bird, is it a plane? no its a badger";
>   }

I loop through and pull out the date and convert it from a NSString to a NSDate.

I try writing it back in using the code;

> [[self.MediaDataArray objectAtIndex:i] replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:Date];

but it errors and i am pretty sure it is because i am not putting it back into the array in the same format, ie just as a date not as date = "date". But lets face it i don't really know!

Am i barking up the wrong tree? Please help, i have got the coding equivalent of writters block, or alternatively am just being really stupid! thanks in advance

Comment: You say that you get an error, but you don't say what it is.

Comment: Yes, you are barking up the wrong tree. An array does not care about the type of objects it contains. What error message do you get?

Comment: 2010-04-29 10:40:23.058 mediaLibrary[1406:207] *** -[NSCFDictionary replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x411beb0
2010-04-29 10:40:23.058 mediaLibrary[1406:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSCFDictionary replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x411beb0'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message says it all: `[self.MediaDataArray objectAtIndex:i]` returns a `NSDictionary`, which obviously does not understand the `replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject:` message. You are confusing dictionaries and arrays.

First, make sure that the dictionary you are dealing with is a `NSMutableDictionary`. Then, change the code to:

```
[[self.MediaDataArray objectAtIndex:i] setObject:Date forKey:@"Date"];
```

Comment: yeah thats magic thanks mate, i create it as a NSMutableArray but load it with a NSMutableDictionary. but that works, so get in!